# get data from table with group and the member

Tags: mysql

I have a complicated query to show it. ( i will just give the example )

Table Car

```
ID     Car_name     Car_category
1      Ferrari      sporty
2      Nissan       SUV
3      Audy         Sporty
4      Honda        City car
5      Mitsubishi   SUV
```

I want my query show this result:

```
Car_category     Car_name

Sporty           Ferrari
                 Audy
SUV              Nissan
                 Mitsubishi
City Car         Honda
```

I have try this query, but wrong..

```
SELECT a.Car_category,
(
    SELECT b.Car_name
    FROM car b 
    WHERE b.Car_category = a.Car_category
    ORDER BY Car_name
    LIMIT 1,1
) as Car_name
FROM car a
GROUP BY a.class
```

is it any solution guys? really need your help, thank you for the attention..

Comment: why don't you just do that in the application level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [**GROUP_CONCAT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) like

```
SELECT car_category,
       group_concat(car_name separator '\n')
FROM `Car`
GROUP BY car_category
```

Check [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9304d/1)

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with a similar issue when starting. I have a different, but I believe more effective answer.

This is what I have in the end:

```
CALL `sandbox`.get_car_categories();
SELECT * FROM `sandbox`.cardemo;

SELECT * FROM `sandbox`.cardemo LIMIT 10;
+--------------+-------------------------+------+
| Car_category | Car_name                | id   |
+--------------+-------------------------+------+
| EURO         | AUDI 5000 TOOTHY        | 2754 |
|              | PORSCHE DURAPHAT        | 2756 |
|              | PORSCHE PREVIDENT       | 2758 |
| AMERICAN     | TAURUS                  | 3    |
|              | WRANGLER                | 123  |
|              | CHEROKEE                | 2842 |
|              | AMPHOCIL                | 2834 |
|              | AMPHOCIN                | 2838 |
|              | ARPHOTEC                | 145  |
|              | ARESTIN                 | 197  |
+--------------+-------------------------+------+
10 rows in set (0.19 sec)
```

This is a super heavy handed approach for a new student. But worth noting particularly if you want this to actually work at the row level if using something like php, etc.

Basically, with stored procedures, it is easy to handle looping and foreach type scenarios with inner and outer loops to obtain the effect you desired, at the specific row level, without `GROUP_CONCAT` etc. solutions.

*You still maintain atomic row level/primary key identifers but can nest under a main category just for aesthetics - this is important if you need the unique `cars.id` of a row*

Adapted for OP code...from the MySQL manual for v5.6 page on Cursors: [Cursors Example](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cursors.html)

First setup the table we want to write to, in a lazy fashion.

```
#### I have a database called `sandbox`. 
#### replace with yours

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `sandbox`.cardemo;
CREATE TABLE `sandbox`.cardemo SELECT Car_category, Car_name, id from car;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sandbox`.cardemo;
```

Now we get into the stored procedure and cursor to build our list table and fill the table we created above:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sandbox`.get_car_categories;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `sandbox`.get_car_categories()
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE a, b, last_a VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT "";
  DECLARE c INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR 
      SELECT Car_category, Car_name, id 
      from car ORDER BY 1,2;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  OPEN cur1;

  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO a, b, c;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    IF a != last_a THEN
      INSERT INTO `sandbox`.cardemo VALUES (a, b,c);
      SET last_a = a;
    ELSE
      INSERT INTO `sandbox`.cardemo VALUES ("", b,c);

    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur1;
END $$
DELIMITER ;





CALL `sandbox`.get_car_categories();
SELECT * FROM `sandbox`.cardemo LIMIT 10;
```